# SCNTechnique pipeline crashing almost immediately when I use DRAW_SCENE

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm new to Metal (and shaders in general). I've been trying to create an `ARSCNView` app using the [MSL spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) and the [SCNTechnique docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique) to apply shaders.

I want a shader pipeline which will let me alter the camera feed view only (`sceneView.scene.background`), but allow all SCNNodes to blend with the *unaltered* camera feed where they overlap. Here's my plan:

### My Plan

**1)** First pass applies my first stylized shader to the scene (which just adjusts color/luma, I've tested it with `DRAW_QUAD` and it works fine) to `DRAW_SCENE` and uses `excludeCategoryMask` to exclude all nodes.

The shader should include some sort of uniform data structure which contains all the other nodes in my scene (currently empty because nodes haven't been rendered yet) and uses their screen space coordinates to cut appropriately sized/positioned shapes in the color filter where the nodes overlap.

**2)** Second pass renders the rest of my nodes (spheres, etc.) with `DRAW_NODE` using standard/default SCNKit shaders.

### Problem

I don't know if this is an effective approach because my app crashes almost immediately with `com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer (15): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xeb52be860)`. When I switch from `DRAW_QUAD` to `DRAW_SCENE`, the shader crashes. I think I'm missing a depth buffer or something.

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct VertexInput_0 {
    float4 position [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition) ]];
    float2 texcoord [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0) ]];
};

struct VertexOutput_0 {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texcoord;
};

// metalVertexShader
vertex VertexOutput_0 scene_filter_vertex_0(VertexInput_0 in [[stage_in]])
{
    VertexOutput_0 out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.texcoord = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);
    return out;
}

// metalFragmentShader
fragment half4 scene_filter_fragment_0(VertexOutput_0 vert [[stage_in]],
                                     texture2d<half, access::sample> scene [[texture(0)]])
{
    constexpr sampler samp = sampler(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::nearest);
    half4 color = scene.sample(samp, vert.texcoord);

    constexpr half3 weights = half3(2, 0.7152, 0.0722);
    color.rgb = half3(dot(color.rgb, weights));


    return color;
}

// Doesn't reach here, crashes before second pass below

struct VertexInput_1 {
    float4 position [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition) ]];
    float2 texcoord [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0) ]];
};

struct VertexOutput_1 {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texcoord;
};

// metalVertexShader
vertex VertexOutput_1 scene_filter_vertex_1(VertexInput_1 in [[stage_in]])
{
    VertexOutput_1 out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.texcoord = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);
    return out;
}

// metalFragmentShader
fragment half4 scene_filter_fragment_1(VertexOutput_1 vert [[stage_in]],
                                     texture2d<half, access::sample> scene [[texture(0)]])
{
    constexpr sampler samp = sampler(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::nearest);
    half4 color = scene.sample(samp, vert.texcoord);

    return color;
}
```

### shaders.metal

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>filter_0</string>
        <string>filter_1</string>
    </array>
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>filter_1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>scene</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>scene_filter_vertex_2</string>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string>scene_filter_fragment_2</string>
        </dict>
        <key>filter_0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string>scene_filter_fragment_0</string>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>scene_filter_vertex_0</string>
            <key>excludeCategoryMask</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>scene</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Why is this crashing? Am I missing a parameter somewhere?

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm trying something similar

Answer (score 0):

it might be `scene_filter_vertex_2` and `scene_filter_fragment_2` need to be renamed `scene_filter_vertex_1` and `scene_filter_fragment_1`